# Print employee hierarchy in java

Tags: java, collections

I was asked this question in an interview but was not able to give efficient solution.

Given an employee class

```
public class Employee {
    int e_id;
    int manager_id;
    String designation;
}
```

Input will have list of employees like CEO,MD,ED,VP,Manager,Associate in any order.
My task was : Given an id of employee, I need to print levels above and below it in sorted order.
CEO will have emp_id and manager_id same.

So I have given id of VP [568,33,VP] then I should print

```
Above levels : 
[1,1,CEO]
[222,1,MD]
[33,222,ED]

Below levels :
[435,568,Manager]
[987,435,Assocaite]
```

So my question is , using java how can you solve it.
If any java 8 feature or collection feature which I can use ?

Comment: And your question is what exactly? And whats unclear to you?

Comment: So my question is , using java how can you solve it. If any java 8 feature or collection feature which I can use ?

Comment: When asking such questions on SO, you are required to provide a lot of detail on what you already tried, narrowing down the section that ur actually unclear with. You have to provide your code attempts and explain it in depth. Please read the rules. This website requires a great effort on asking a question well (and also on answering them well).